# My Edittext starts invisible, how do I make it editable when visible?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Normally I'd do it in XML or set it from code with

```
.setEnabled(true);
```

but I can't get it working in this case. In a nutshell, the `EditText` is set to invisible, with a `CheckBox` click it fades into view and should be editable but... it's not. The `EditText` fades in and fades out as intended but text can't be typed in the box... What to do?

Here's my code :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addcontact);

//      initialise the edittexts
        textcategory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textCategory);
        textcategory.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
        fadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);

//      lets be able to manipuate checkbox,
//        make other things visible or not when checked
        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    // Now Set your animation
                    textcategory.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
                    fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

                } else {

                    // Now Set your animation
                    textcategory.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);

                }

            }
        });

    }
```

And my XML :

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:hint="Select a Category"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textCategory"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: Where you have written code for edittext visible, invisible or editable ?

Comment: Try to use View.GONE instead of View.INVISIBLE

Comment: @Array. I don't think that would solve the problem. View.GONE would be just like my EditText does not exist at all, letting other views take the space of it. View.INVISIBLE is more like a placeholder - you can't see the view yet it takes up space set in XML or in Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've hid your `EditText` with the following:

```
textcategory.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Then, instead of `setEnabled(true)`, you should call  the following:

```
textcategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

To show it again.

`setEnabled()` should be called only if you've explicitly disabled your `View`.

Comment: Aha. So even though it becomes ''visible'' with the fade in, you still have to set the visibility to VISIBLE.

Answer (score 1):

setVisibility of textView instead of `fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);` after animation end.

Answer (score 1):

In your xml add this line

```
android:alpha="0"
```

Then remove this line from your activity

```
textcategory.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

For animating you can directly use ViewPropertyAnimation as in

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           if (isChecked) {
                    // Now Set your animation
                   textcategory.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(1000).start();
                } else {

                    // Now Set your animation
                    textcategory.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Still couldn't get it to work with adding that to xml and removing setvisibility. Your ViewPropertyAnimation looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
yourEditText.setFocusable(true);
yourEditText.setClickable(true);
```